# DreamFactory- How to change default assest storing path in DF

Tags: apex, migration-tool, migration

I am not able to figure out where DreamFactory is storing all assets on System.
Is there any way we can change that.

Comment: Have you contacted their support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which operating system you are using DreamFactory stores your SnapShots in the following directories:

**On Windows:**

> C:\Users\[username]\Documents\DreamFactory\downloads\www.dreamfactory.net\codebase\utilities

(where [username] is your username)

**On Mac:**

> ~/Documents/DreamFactory/downloads/www.dreamfactory.net/codebase/utilities

You can also change the directory path where your SnapShots are stored on your machine. If you would like to know how to change where your SnapShots are stored on your machine, please reach out to our support team at salesforcesuppport@dreamfactory.com.